# How to add AWS SSO SAML Authentication for .Net Core Application

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, asp.net-core, single-sign-on, saml-2.0

Which DLL we can use to configure AWS SSO SAML in .Net Core.Saml2, Here below I am adding a sample code for AZURE AD SSO.

```
 // Saml2 Authentication
            services.AddAuthentication(sharedOptions =>
            {
                sharedOptions.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                sharedOptions.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                sharedOptions.DefaultSignOutScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                sharedOptions.DefaultChallengeScheme = "Saml2";
            })
              .AddSaml2(options =>

              
                  options.SPOptions.EntityId = new EntityId(ssoSettings.EntityID);
                  options.IdentityProviders.Add(
                  new IdentityProvider(
                    new EntityId(ssoSettings.IdentityProvider), options.SPOptions)
                  {
                      MetadataLocation = ssoSettings.MetadataLocation
                  });
              })
```